# How will DraggableScrollSheet disappear when the draggablescrollsheet controller is scrolled down?

Tags: flutter

I want to make a DraggableScrollSheet, when scrolled to the bottom (not scroll the content inside the DraggableScrollSheet, but the draggablescrollsheet itself) then the draggablescrollsheet will disappear.

I hope someone can help me

[This is my Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbzgN.png)

[The DraggableScrollSheet will trigger after pressing this icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vonez.jpg)

```
class DetailAnimals extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imgAnimal;
  final String name;
  final String kategori;
  final String jenisMakanan;
  final String deskripsi;
  final String audio;
  const DetailAnimals(
      {super.key,
      required this.imgAnimal,
      required this.name,
      required this.deskripsi,
      required this.audio,
      required this.kategori,
      required this.jenisMakanan});

  @override
  State<DetailAnimals> createState() => _DetailAnimalsState();
}

class _DetailAnimalsState extends State<DetailAnimals> {
  bool showSheet = false;
  late ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.removeListener(_scrollListener);
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _scrollListener() {
    if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      setState(() {
        showSheet = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        showSheet = false;
      });
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFfab800),
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 250), () {
                Get.back();
              });
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios)
                .animate(delay: const Duration(milliseconds: 250))
                .slideX(begin: -2, end: 0)),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          //this is will be my content
          ),
          !showSheet
              ? DraggableScrollableSheet(
                  // this controller should be gone if _scrollListeners run
                  initialChildSize: 0.9,
                  minChildSize: showSheet ? 0.0 : 0.1,
                  maxChildSize: 1,
                  builder: (context, scrollController) {
                    return Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                        ),
                        color: Color(0xFF2e2e2e),
                      ),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: animalsList.length,
                        controller: scrollController,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            leading: Image.asset(
                              animalsList[index]['imagePath']!,
                              width: 50,
                              height: 50,
                            ),
                            title: Text(animalsList[index]['name']!),
                            subtitle: Text(animalsList[index]['deskripsi']!),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                )
              : const SizedBox.shrink(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have solved those issues in this way:**

you can use a ScrollController to track the scroll position. When the user scrolls down, you can dynamically adjust the maxChildSize property of the DraggableScrollSheet to make it disappear by setting it to 0.0. When the user scrolls up, you can set maxChildSize back to its original value to make the bottom sheet reappear. This way, the bottom sheet's visibility changes based on the user's scrolling behavior.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('DraggableScrollSheet Example'),
        ),
        body: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return MyBottomSheetContent();
            },
          );
        },
        child: Text('Open Bottom Sheet'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyBottomSheetContent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyBottomSheetContentState createState() => _MyBottomSheetContentState();
}

class _MyBottomSheetContentState extends State<MyBottomSheetContent> {
  final _controller = ScrollController();
  bool _isVisible = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(_scrollListener);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.removeListener(_scrollListener);
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _scrollListener() {
    if (_controller.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
      // User scrolled down
      setState(() {
        _isVisible = false;
      });
    } else if (_controller.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.forward) {
      // User scrolled up
      setState(() {
        _isVisible = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DraggableScrollableSheet(
      initialChildSize: 0.5,
      minChildSize: 0.1,
      maxChildSize: _isVisible ? 0.8 : 0.0, // Change maxChildSize dynamically
      builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.grey[300],
          child: ListView.builder(
            controller: scrollController,
            itemCount: 100,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text('Item $index'),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this is not what I want. this is what I want
u can check this video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NZCXq_VR5QCkIYGrBNzhNoqINERmYXZS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: okay thanks but can you explain in details?